# How can I log out of ServerFault?

Tags: discussion, serverfault, login

Usually when my PC is on and my browser is on I am always logged into ServerFault, and I don't care much about that, since it is at my home PC.

However, I've been into a friend house yesterday and logged into ServerFault from his PC, but then I've noticed that I can't log out?!

I am using my GMail acc. to log in here, and I tried to log out from GMail, but that didn't help either.

There is no LogOut button, and **the only thing that loged me out was the deletion of the browser cookies.**

**Why there is no logout button on all of stack exchange sites?**

Comment: While Iain's answer is correct, of course, I have to say you make a good point - logout should be more visible, or at least more easily discoverable.

Comment: FYI if you are not using your personal computer, then you should probably be using the incognito/private browsing feature of the Internet browser, so that none of your cookies/authentication/etc gets saved for any service/site.

Comment: Good point, I always forget on that feature..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Float your mouse pointer over your name in the top bar and click on logout in the popout that appears.

[image]

This will take you to a logout page

---

The recent changes to the top bar have moved logout, it's now in the main StackExchage drop down

[image]

Comment: Hahaha omg! It realy is the only place and it is very hard to spot :). Thanx for the answer buddy :)

Comment: Umm, where did you say that was? Can you show a larger screenshot? I can't seem to find the spot you showed.

Comment: @Marki: They moved it when they updated the top bar.

Comment: Where did "logout" get moved to? I can't see it no matter how I hover.

Comment: Check out the cheeseburger on the right - yeesh